# Iterative through elasticsearch result object array in express/node

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, express, elasticsearch

This is related to the a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40292191/inserting-multiple-results-to-req-object-in-express-js-route) I have asked previously. I have corrected my route according the answer give by @Val. With that I have an array containing arrays which has JSON objects. Ex:

```
[
  [{_index:'myIndex',_type:'myType',_source:{name:'Name',age:25}}, 
   {_index:'myIndex',_type:'myType',_source:{name:'Name',age:25}}
  ],
  [{_index:'myIndex',_type:'myType',_source:{name:'Name',age:25}},
   {_index:'myIndex',_type:'myType',_source:{name:'Name',age:25}}
  ]
]
```

So in my ejs file I am iterating through array as follows.

```
<% if(locals.players){ %>
<% for(var i=0;locals.players.length;i++){ %>
    //some more code
    <% var tp = locals.players[i]; %>
         <% for(var j=0;tp.length;j++){ %>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    Name:<%= tp[j]._source.name %><br>
                    Age:<%= tp[j]._source.age %>
                </li>
            </ul>
    <% } %>
<% } } %>
```

But I receive an error 'property _source undefined'. Just to add more details: the results array is coming from elasticsearch query. My intention is to print more results of another query which has objects from 1-D array. Second array contains arrays of results which correspond to each object in 1-D array.

Comment: Based on that other question you referenced, it is not clear what you have in your `locals` variable.

Comment: I render the index page in renderResults and the index.ejs contains the another ejs which is given above. There are two results arrays in renderResults: teams and players. To access those arrays we can use syntax like `<% if(locals.teams){%>
       <% for(var i=0;i<locals.teams.length;i++){ %>
        <ul><li>
                Name:<%= locals.teams[i]._source.name %>
                </li></ul> <%}}%>`

Comment: Ok, I got that part, but how does your array look like when your code fails?

Comment: The array that I have posted with my question is similar to that. When the array just have JSON objects like `[{_index:myIndex,_type:myType,_source:{a:a, b:b}},{_index:myIndex,_type:myType,_source:{a:a, b:b}},{_index:myIndex,_type:myType,_source:{a:a, b:b}}]` I can access to them `<%= locals.teams[i]._source.a%>` in a loop.

Comment: I found a error in assigning nested array to `var tp`. Instead of that I changed the loop as `for(var j=0;j<locals.players[i][j].length;j++){..}`. Now I don't have errors. But no display of players array data. Working on it now..