# Display object properties values in each loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js, handlebarshelper

I have an array known as `sem` containing multiple objects and an object known as `result` containing properties `href` and `content` which contain strings. They are being rendered to the view as follows:

Here i am using `async` to run functions in parallel so that i can pass 2 different variables into the view. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13783377/send-multiple-db-query-results-to-a-single-view-using-express)

**app.js**

```
res.render('sem/semester', {
  sem: sem,
  result:result
});
```

The array `sem` contains:

```
sem: [
{semNumber: 2, collegeName: 'blalblalbla'},
{semNumber: 3, collegeName: 'dfhgfh'}
{semNumber: 4, collegeName: 'dsfdsdsf'}
];
```

The object `result` contains:

```
result: {href: 'url', content: 'Some text'}
```

**TARGET**

In **semester.handlebars**

```
{{#each sem}}
    <div>{{semNumber}}</div>
    <div>{{collegeName}}</div>
    <a href="{{result.href}}">{{result.content}}</a>
{{/each}}
```

I did the above, but the properties of `result` i.e `href` & `content` do not get displayed in an `each` loop.

**Output must be:**

```
2
blablablabla
Some text
3
dfhgfh
Some text
4
dsfdsdsf
Some text
```

**EDIT:**
(The url contains a handlebar expression which would render from the array sem)

Example: `/marks/edit_marks/semester_number={{semNumber}}/{{id}}`

Comment: Try `{{../result.href}}`

Comment: Thanks @elclanrs . It worked, but handlebar expression is rendered as static text in the href. Sorry i forgot to mention it when i wrote the post :(

Comment: Could you please update your question with full html example of expected output generated by single iteration of `{{each}}` and json data for which it was generated?